# How to left join on mysql between two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hi i'm trying to left join from a vessel table to daily_volume table. The two table contains the following data:

(vessel_table)

[image]

(daily_volume table)

[image]

Let's say today is 2019-07-08. I would like to left join vessel_table to daily_volume table in a way it will show this output as brand new:

[image]

My current sql statement is this but doesn't seem to achieve the above output:

SELECT * FROM vessel LEFT JOIN daily_volume ON vessel.vessel_id = daily_volume.vessel_id WHERE daily_volume.date is null

Can anyone help me how should i query to produce the output i need? Thanks

i have tried looking stackoverflow but to no avail

SELECT * FROM vessel LEFT JOIN daily_volume ON vessel.vessel_id = daily_volume.vessel_id WHERE daily_volume.date is null

### vessel_id    volume      date

1             null        null
2             null        null
3             null        null
4             null        null
5             null        null
6             null        null

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a condition on the current date in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT v.vessel_id, dv.volume, dv.date
FROM vessel v LEFT JOIN
     daily_volume dv
     ON dv.vessel_id = dv.vessel_id AND
        dv.date = curdate();
```